# Convert Json String to Json Array Circe Scala?

Tags: scala, circe

So I have here (Note that this is not syntactically correct, i just want to show you the idea)

```
js = “a1,a2”
```

how do I convert a circe.JSON string to a circe.JSON array?

```
      expected js => [“a1”,”a2”]
```

Goal is for function to return [“a1”,”a2”] as Array[Byte]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, this is not very typical case, `circe` does not provide such behavior out of the box, so you will need implement own `Encoder` and `Decoder`. Luckily, it is fairly easy to do with this lib.

Please, see code example below:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

val separator = ","
// Implement own `Encoder` to render array of string as JSON string, separated with comma inside
implicit val encoder: Encoder[Array[String]] = Encoder[String].contramap(_.mkString(separator))

// Implement own `Decoder` to parse JSON string as array
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Array[String]] = Decoder[String].map(_.split(separator))

// Class added for sake of example, because I guess you will use string array as a part of another structure
case class Foo(a: Array[String]) {
  // override toString, because array toString works as default Object toString, which is not really readable
  // Made for example readability, you don't need to do in your code
  override def toString: String = s"Foo(a: ${a.mkString(", ")})"
}

val foo = Foo(Array("a1", "a2"))
val json = foo.asJson

println(json.noSpaces)
println(json.as[Foo])
```

Which produces next result:

```
{"a":"a1,a2"}
Right(Foo(a: a1,a2))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. When did you use the encoder and decoder? Thank you

Comment: @CodeGeek `Decoder` used to parse json to some `T` (`Array[String]` in this case) and `Encoder`, vice versa, format some `T` to json. It is the same as Serializer/ Deserializer in other protocol libraries.